# What does 'As String * 25' mean when declaring a variable?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to understand what this code means:

```
Dim Duplicatecheck(0 To 10000) As String * 25
```

I see that it is a string array, but what does "* 25" do? I have looked high and low about vb6 arrays, but there isn't anything I can see that explains it.

Comment: Just to be clear, its not an array feature. Its the data / variable type.

Comment: @DaveInCaz That is why I couldn't find any reference to it at all, lol

Answer (score 5):

This is called a [Fixed-length string](https://www.example-code.com/vb/fixedLength.asp). Your code declares an array of string where each element has a 25 characters length. Take this code, for example:

```
Dim s As String * 3

s = "123"
Debug.Print s   ' Prints "123"

s = "abcdef"
Debug.Print s   ' Prints "abc"

s = "a"
Debug.Print s   ' Prints "a  " <-- Notice the two trailing spaces.
```

Comment: That is it!!! Thank you very much. Stackoverflow sent me a notice that my question was a duplicate, and after reading the other question/answer I agreed. I don't know how I didn't find that earlier question before. Can I choose that your comment was an answer as well, or just that my question was a duplicate?

Comment: @paulgc If you think the answer helped you, then yes, you can accept it too. Note that [duplicate questions aren't always a bad thing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).